# Count number of users in groups

Tags: linux, users, group

There are file /etc/group. The format is "group name:password:identifier:list of users separated with spaces"
How to print NAME of group with biggest number of users? Thanks.

Comment: Last time I checked, group members were a comma-separated list, not space-separated. What Unix are you on?

Comment: Counting strictly based on the number of (secondary) group members listed in /etc/group, or total members (including users with that group as primary)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am preparing for a test and it's a task text

Comment: @JeffSchaller only listed in /etc/group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getent group | awk -F '[,:]' '{ print $1, NF - 3 }' | sort -k2,2n
```

This will output a list of group names followed by number of group members, sorted by the number of group members. I'm assuming the text of the question is wrong and that the list of group members is comma-separated.

It would be easy to parse the result of this to pick out the one(s) that have the most group members.

`getent group` will get the current list of groups on the same format as the file `/etc/group`. This command will also query a directory service like NIS/YP or LDAP, if one is in use.

The `awk` code will divide the lines up into fields based on commas or colons and print the first field (the group name) followed by the total number of fields minus three (the minus three is to not count the group name, password, and GID fields).

The final `sort` will do a numerical sort based only on the second column, which is the number of group members.